# Rename the same column for all excel files in a folder in R

Tags: r, excel

I have multiple excel files in a folder, so I want to clean each file in the folder, then append all the excel files together. I want to rename the first column of all excel files so I am using the following codes :

```
filelist<- list.files(pattern="*.xlsx")
DF <- lapply(filelist,function(i) {
Fu <- read_excel(i, sheet="XX")
colnames(Fu[[i]])[1] <- "Column 1"})
```

However, I got an error message:  Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = "SCENARIO_KEY") : 
  attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions. How to fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `lapply`, itself, we can rename.  The `i` in the loop are each of the element of 'filelist'.  It cannot be used for subsetting 'Fu'.  Instead, we can directly subset the column based on the index as 'Fu' is a single data.frame within each `list` element

```
DF <- lapply(filelist,function(i) {
          Fu <- read_excel(i, sheet="XX")
          colnames(Fu)[1] <- "Column 1"
          Fu
     })
```

Even if the index is right, when we subset a data.frame with `[[` to get the column, it returns a `vector` and there is dim or column names attribute for a vector

```
mtcars[[1]]
```

is a `vector`

and doing the assignment returns the error because the colnames is `NULL`

```
colnames(mtcars[[1]])
#NULL

colnames(mtcars[[1]]) <- "new column"
```

> Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = "new column") : 
>     attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions